# Union All Help Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have six different select statements used for SSRS reporting purpose.

Below are two statements out of those. I need help on how to do `Union All` for bellow and combine all statements into one.

```
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATE='04-Aug-2015'
DECLARE @ToDate AS DATE='05-Aug-2015'

SELECT 
    A.LBrCode AS BranchCode,
    (SELECT B.Name 
     FROM D001003 B 
     WHERE A.LBrCode = B.PBrCode) AS BranchName,
    C.PrdCd AS Product,
    SUM(D.FcyTrnAmt) AS Amount
FROM 
    D009022 A 
INNER JOIN 
    D009021 C ON substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = C.PrdCd
              AND A.LBrCode = C.LBrCode
LEFT JOIN 
    D009040 D ON A.PrdAcctId = D.VcrAcctId
              AND substring(D.VcrAcctId, 1, 8) = C.PrdCd
              AND A.LBrCode = D.LBrCode
WHERE 
    A.AcctStat <> 3 
    AND A.DateOpen >= @FromDate 
    AND A.DateOpen <= @ToDate
    AND C.ModuleType = 11
    AND D.DrCr = 'D' 
    AND D.CanceledFlag <> 'C'
GROUP BY 
    A.LBrCode, C.PrdCd
ORDER BY 
    A.LBrCode

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    A.LBrCode AS BranchCode,
    (SELECT B.Name FROM D001003 B WHERE A.LBrCode = B.PBrCode) AS BranchName,
    C.PrdCd AS Product,
    SUM(A.ActTotBalFcy) AS Balance
FROM 
    D009022 A 
INNER JOIN 
    D009021 C ON substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = C.PrdCd
              AND A.LBrCode = C.LBrCode
WHERE 
    C.ModuleType = 11
    AND A.AcctStat <> 3 
    AND A.DateOpen >= @FromDate 
    AND A.DateOpen <= @ToDate
GROUP BY 
    A.LBrCode, C.PrdCd
ORDER BY 
    A.LBrCode
```

Comment: you can use CTE(Common table expression)

Comment: Move D's conditions from WHERE clause to ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. (As it now it executes as a regular inner join...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only apply one `ORDER BY` clause to affect the order of results, and it has to apply to the entire result set. If, as I suspect, you want all of the results from the top query to appear before results from the bottom query, you need to add another column to the data to allow that to happen:

```
SELECT A.LBrCode AS BranchCode,
(SELECT B.Name FROM D001003 B WHERE A.LBrCode=B.PBrCode) AS BranchName,
C.PrdCd AS Product,
sum(D.FcyTrnAmt) AS Amount,
1 as ResultSet
FROM D009022 A INNER JOIN D009021 C
ON substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)=C.PrdCd
AND A.LBrCode=C.LBrCode
LEFT JOIN D009040 D
ON A.PrdAcctId=D.VcrAcctId
AND substring(D.VcrAcctId,1,8)=C.PrdCd
AND A.LBrCode=D.LBrCode
WHERE A.AcctStat <> 3 AND A.DateOpen>=@FromDate AND A.DateOpen<=@ToDate
AND C.ModuleType=11
AND D.DrCr='D' 
AND D.CanceledFlag<>'C'

GROUP BY A.LBrCode, C.PrdCd
--ORDER BY A.LBrCode

UNION ALL

SELECT A.LBrCode AS BranchCode,
(SELECT B.Name FROM D001003 B WHERE A.LBrCode=B.PBrCode) AS BranchName,
C.PrdCd AS Product,
sum(A.ActTotBalFcy) AS Balance,
2
FROM D009022 A INNER JOIN D009021 C
ON substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)=C.PrdCd
AND A.LBrCode=C.LBrCode
WHERE C.ModuleType=11
AND A.AcctStat <> 3 
AND A.DateOpen>=@FromDate AND A.DateOpen<=@ToDate

GROUP BY A.LBrCode, C.PrdCd
ORDER BY ResultSet,BranchCode
```

Answer (score 1):

For a union to work both queries must have the same number of columns and be compatible data types, you may want to convert column data types to ensure they are the same.  For example you may have issues with your Amount and Balance columns of the data types are incompatible.

You cannot order each individual statement in the union, this does not make sense as you will be producing a single output.

But, with these points in mind, your query should work as it stands.

```
declare @test table (a int, b varchar(10))

insert into @test values (10,'test1')
insert into @test values (20,'test2')

select 
 a, b
from 
 @test

 UNION ALL 

select 
 a, b
from 
 @test 

 order by a
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your query, I am assuming that your `sum` calculation is the only difference between all your queries.

For example, the only difference between the two `union all` queries above is the field used for `summation` and the `where` clause filters (`D.DrCr='D' AND D.CanceledFlag<>'C'`). If that is true, then you could just use `CASE WHEN` statement to handle all your 6 different scenarios like this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATE = '04-Aug-2015';
DECLARE @ToDate AS DATE = '05-Aug-2015';

SELECT A.LBrCode AS BranchCode
    ,(
        SELECT B.NAME
        FROM D001003 B
        WHERE A.LBrCode = B.PBrCode
        ) AS BranchName
    ,C.PrdCd AS Product
    ,CASE 
        WHEN D.DrCr = 'D' AND D.CanceledFlag <> 'C'
            THEN sum(A.ActTotBalFcy)
        /*add other remaining conditions here */
     ELSE sum(D.FcyTrnAmt)
        END AS Amount
FROM D009022 A
INNER JOIN D009021 C ON substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = C.PrdCd
    AND A.LBrCode = C.LBrCode
LEFT JOIN D009040 D ON A.PrdAcctId = D.VcrAcctId
    AND substring(D.VcrAcctId, 1, 8) = C.PrdCd
    AND A.LBrCode = D.LBrCode
WHERE A.AcctStat <> 3
    AND A.DateOpen >= @FromDate
    AND A.DateOpen <= @ToDate
    AND C.ModuleType = 11
GROUP BY A.LBrCode
    ,C.PrdCd
ORDER BY A.LBrCode
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
declare @var1 = value1;
declare @var2 = value2
;with cte1 AS(
Select statement1
UNION ALL
Select statement2
UNION ALL
Select statement3
UNION ALL
Select statement4
UNION ALL
Select statement5
UNION ALL
Select statement6
)
Select * From CTE1
```

Comment: But how to use group by?

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 CTE's then:

```
SELECT *
FROM CTE1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY ____
ORDER BY ______
```

You cannot have more then 1 GROUP BY and ORDER BY when doing a UNION ALL